# How can I make setInterval work even when the tab in Chrome is inactive?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tampermonkey

Please help me figure it out. I am writing a custom script for Tampermonkey.

Briefly about the script: the script updates the page on the site every 3 minutes, checks for the presence of an object and, if there is one, clicks on it.

Problem: when the tab is inactive (focus on another Google tab or the window is minimized), the script does not work, the setInterval and setTimeout timer stop working and the script does not update or search for anything. How to fix this situation?

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         User Script
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       None
// @match        https://www.twitch.tv/drops/inventory
// @icon         https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=tampermonkey.net
// @require      https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js
// @grant        none
/* globals jQuery, $, waitForKeyElements */
// ==/UserScript==

$(window).load(function(){
    'use strict';

    setTimeout(function(){

        function SearchController(){
            var i = 0;
            var result = '';
            $('.dYkLvU').each(function(){
                if ($(this).find('button').find('.phMMp').text() == 'Click'){
                    $(this).find('button').find('.phMMp').trigger('click');
                }
            });
        }
        SearchController();

        setInterval(function(){
            location.reload();
        }, 60000);

    }, 4000);

});
```

I know about this thing (https://github.com/turuslan/HackTimer), but for some reason it doesn't work in Tampermonkey.

Comment: Try [this article](https://medium.com/@adithyaviswam/overcoming-browser-throttling-of-setinterval-executions-45387853a826).

Comment: @wOxxOm, Thank you so much for the article. How to translate the code to JQ? With "React.js" I don't know how to use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your need correctly, here an example of userscript that check some element and refresh the page every 10sec. It's working even if inactive or not focus.

You might need to ajust regarding your situation.

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    if (window.location.href.indexOf('google') > 0) { //only if url contains 'google'
        checkAndClick();
        window.setTimeout(reload, 10000); //10sec
    }
    function reload() {
        window.location.reload();
    }
    function checkAndClick() {

        console.log('check and click');

        $('.dYkLvU').each(function(){
            if ($(this).find('button').find('.phMMp').text() == 'Click'){
                $(this).find('button').find('.phMMp').trigger('click');
            }
        });
    }
})();
```

Note: if you want to active/deactivate, a suggestion would be to add a button on the page, and play with GM_setValue / GM_getValue

Comment: The browser throttles `setTimeout()` in the background, this does nothing to bypass that.

Comment: @MatthewRead, it's working great from my side (it's running all day long even if the session is locked). Maybe because in this snippet the page is reloaded each time?

Comment: I am also using the full page reload, unfortunately.  Very odd that the behavior would be different for you.  Possibly the page you're using runs into one of these exceptions, like using WebRTC? https://developer.chrome.com/blog/timer-throttling-in-chrome-88/#intensive-throttling

Comment: @MatthewRead only chained `setTimeout` are related (and `setInterval`). Do you confirm this snippet with one-time timers is not working from your side ?